# Concatenate query with another query with case statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this

```
SELECT
  ((SELECT
    F_Cat_Code
  FROM T_Category
  WHERE F_Cat_name = 'Furniture')
  + (SELECT
    F_L1Cat_Code
  FROM T_L1Category
  WHERE F_L1Cat_Name = 'Table')
  + (SELECT
    F_L2Cat_Code
  FROM T_L2Category
  WHERE F_L2Cat_Name = 'Tea Table')
  )
```

The output of this query `0541123` in this I want to add one more condition

```
select Max(F_Serial_No) 
from T_assets 
where F_Cat_Code='05' and F_L1Cat_Code = '41' and 
      F_L2Cat_Code ='123'
```

If this query result is null, then I want to show value `054112300001`

If that query have some value for example `00002` then I want to show output after incrementing by 1, example `054112300003`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT
  ((SELECT
    F_Cat_Code
  FROM T_Category
  WHERE F_Cat_name = 'Furniture')
  + (SELECT
    F_L1Cat_Code
  FROM T_L1Category
  WHERE F_L1Cat_Name = 'Table')
  + (SELECT
    F_L2Cat_Code
  FROM T_L2Category
  WHERE F_L2Cat_Name = 'Tea Table')
  )
  + (select ISNULL(REPLACE(STR(Max(F_Serial_No)+1,5),' ',0),'00001') 
     from T_assets 
     where 
     F_Cat_Code='05' and F_L1Cat_Code = '41' and F_L2Cat_Code ='123'
     )
```

Comment: sir select Max(F_Serial_No) 
from T_assets 
where F_Cat_Code='05' and F_L1Cat_Code = '41' and 
      F_L2Cat_Code ='123' this value coming not null then i want to increment that

Comment: @jasjas Edited my answer. Besides the increment ("+1") I added padding (that means, that the value is given back with leading zeros (34 => 00034), to ensure a width of 5. Hope this is what you need...

Comment: @jasjas One more hint: Please be aware, that your other parts **must** have a value. Otherwise the full string will be `NULL`. Best is, to add `ISNULL()` whereever `NULL` might be the return value...

Comment: @jasjas, I saw that you were just around... Is this question still open? Do you need any further help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  SELECT
      (cast((SELECT
        F_Cat_Code
      FROM T_Category
      WHERE F_Cat_name = 'Furniture') as varchar(max))
      + cast((SELECT
        F_L1Cat_Code
      FROM T_L1Category
      WHERE F_L1Cat_Name = 'Table') as varchar(max))
      + cast((SELECT
        F_L2Cat_Code
      FROM T_L2Category
      WHERE F_L2Cat_Name = 'Tea Table') as varchar(max))
      )+cast((select coalesce(Max(F_Serial_No)+1,'00001' )
    from T_assets 
    where F_Cat_Code='05' and F_L1Cat_Code = '41' and 
          F_L2Cat_Code ='123') as varchar(max))
```